# How to declare member variable in python base class which can be accessed in derived

Tags: python, class

Maybe I am doing it wrong because I am thinking about how C++ classes work.

But I have a set of classes, see below, which have a set of HTTP headers (it is my attempt at encapsulating HTTP requests).  For example, the base class will have the most generic header while derived classes will have more specialised headers.

In the base class, I cannot just have header on a line by itself.  Doing that gave me a syntax error.  so doing like below and setting to be a dictionary (which it is).  But if I do that when I run I get:

```
>>> Unhandled exception while debugging...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\rq_module.py", line 1, in <module>
    class httprequest:
  File "C:\Python27\rq_module.py", line 2, in httprequest
    header  #dict of headers
NameError: name 'header' is not defined


class httprequest:
    header = dict()  #dict of headers
    def __init__(self):
        #add standard headers
        header = { 'User-Agent' :  'Test Python http client v0.1' }

    def send(self):
        print "Sending base httprequest"

class get_httprequest(httprequest):
    """GET http requests class"""

    def send(self):
        print "Sending GET http request"


class post_httprequest(httprequest):
    """POST http request class"""
    def __init__(self):
        header += { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' } #all data sent in json form

    def send(self):
        print "Sending POST http request"
```

How do I create a member variable in the base class which can also be accessed in the derived classes?

I am using Python 2.7

EDIT.  This is my update based on my understanding of responses.  It does appear to work :)

I was getting a TypeError but it seems I only saw that in PythonWin debugger.  Not when I run without debugger.

```
class httprequest(object):
    header = dict()  #dict of headers
    def __init__(self):
        print "httprequest ctor"
        self.header['User-Agent'] = 'Test Python http client v0.1'

    def send(self):
        print "Sending base httprequest"

class get_httprequest(httprequest):
    """GET http requests class"""

    def send(self):
        print "Sending GET http request"


class post_httprequest(httprequest):
    """POST http request class"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(post_httprequest, self).__init__()
        super(post_httprequest, self).header['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        print "post_httprequest ctor"


    def send(self):
        print "Sending POST http request"
```

Comment: As a side note: Always use new-style classes (`class httprequest(object):`), not classic classes (`class httprequest`) in Python 2.x.

Comment: StoryTeller's deleted answer had a very useful comment: You should use a framework for working with HTTP rather than doing it yourself, unless you're doing it to learn HTTP or something. The stdlib comes with everything you need, and there are even better libraries out there (like `requests`).

Comment: @abarnert Understood, I am learning Python, HTTP.

Comment: Your updated version still has a problem: you're still defining `header` as a class attribute of `httprequest` instead of an instance attribute. It will "work" as long as you only ever have one `httprequest` instance; otherwise, they'll all share the same copy of `headers`. So, for example, after any `POST`, every `GET` you send will have "application/json Content-Type. Also, if you're accessing data attributes like `header` through a `super` call, you're almost always doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instance variables are always accessed through the class instance itself. Inside the method, this is (by convention) known as `self`. So you need to use `self.headers` etc.

Note though that by defining `headers` at the top of the class, you have defined a *class* variable which is shared by all members. You don't want this, and there is no need to define `headers` there. Just assign it within `__init__`.

Plus, as StoryTeller points out, you'll need to call the superclass `__init__` method manually inside the derived class methods, since that defines the attribute in the first place:

```
super(post_httprequest, self).__init__()
```

And in order for that to work, as abarnert points out, you'll need to inherit your base class from `object`.

Finally, please do use PEP8-compliant names: `PostHttpRequest`, etc.

Comment: When you say "assign within __init__" you mean ditch idea of header variable?  Can you shed more light please.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could be clearer. You should do `self.headers = {whatever}`, without defining that first at the class level.

Comment: @user619818: Read the tutorial section [A First Look at Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes). There's a lot of important info there, including the difference between class attributes and instance attributes, and how to define instance attributes in your `__init__` method. Also, since you said you're coming from C++: Python instance attributes and class attributes are roughly equivalent to regular members and static members in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to your `header` variable by prefixing it with `self.`

```
class httprequest:
    header = dict()  #dict of headers
    def __init__(self):
        #add standard headers
        self.header = { 'User-Agent' :  'Test Python http client v0.1' }

    def send(self):
        print "Sending base httprequest"
```

You can think of `self` as an equivalent of java, c++, etc... 's `this` keyword: it refers to the current instance.

Here, you're defining `header` as a class attribute, which means it accessible either with
`httprequest.header`, `self.header` (from inside the class) or `my_instance.header` (from outside the class).

You could make it an instance variable (only accessible through `` `self `` or an instance's name) by declaring it in the `__init__` method:

```
class httprequest:

    def __init__(self):
        #add standard headers
        self.header = { 'User-Agent' :  'Test Python http client v0.1' }

    def send(self):
        print "Sending base httprequest"
```

Here, you'll probably want to keep it at the class level, though.

Comment: Isn't that (the first code) just gonna create an instance variable with the same name as the class variable and use that instead?

Comment: I think you're right. Reading the class variable from the instance causes no problem, but setting it will create a new one on the instance.
I'm used to treat those as pseudo constants and not modify them, so i didn't notice.
Modifying the dictionnary in place (instead of reasigning it as I did) should not cause any trouble tho - You'd still access the class var and modify the right one.